# ASP.net HttpResponse drops everything except body

Tags: asp.net

I've been working on a really old ASP.net project. For some specific request, I want to respond with binary data to the client, so I wrote the following code:

```
public class MyHttpHandler : IHttpHandler {
  public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context) {
    var response = context.Response;

    #region weird behavior

    response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;  // Some post on SO suggests doing this, but doesn't work for me.
    response.ClearHeaders();  // Don't know if this helps, but at least won't hurt.
    response.StatusCode = 201;
    response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    response.Headers["X-Custom-Header"] = "foo";
    response.Flush();  // Adding Flush() here won't work

    #endregion

    using(
      var input = new FileStream(
        @"C:\path\to\binary-file", 
        FileMode.Open,
        FileAccess.Read
      )
    ) {
      var output = response.OutputStream;
      var bufferSize = 1024;
      var buffer = new byte[bufferSize];
      var readLength = 0;
      do {
        readLength = input.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
        output.Write(buffer, 0, readLength);
        output.Flush();
      } while(readLength > 0);
    }
  }
}
```

The weird thing is that although I got the right response body, the status code, content type and custom header I manually set are lost. The actual content type I got is always `text/html; charset=utf-8`, and the actual status code is always `200`. How can this be?

Comment: I tried the same code. Fiddler output: 
HTTP/1.1 201 Created
Cache-Control: private
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
X-Custom-Header: foo
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?RDpcUHJvamVsZXJcS2FyZGVsZW5cS29kXEthcmRlbGVuLldlYi5BcHBcbC55?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 30 Mar 2018 08:27:52 GMT

Comment: @selami Thanks a lot for trying. I created a vanilla ASP.net project too, and this piece of code works fine. However, in the real project I'm working on, for some reason this does not work. I've tried to find all the places that set or clear the headers, but there's none. There's no reverse proxy in front of IIS that changes the responses, either. I feel I'm getting mad thanks to this project.

Comment: I was looking at httpresponse on msdn and `response.Headers` is only a `{ get; }`. Maybe give `response.AppendHeader` a shot.

Comment: @wazz `response.AppendHeader` is deprecated and exists only for backward compatibility. I've also tried that though, but had no luck.

Comment: deprecated one is `response.AddHeader`.

Comment: @wazz You're right, sorry. However, appending headers are not acceptable because I don't want headers like `Content-Type` appear twice in the response.